# Unable to create a new version of a 2GP package depending on an Ancestor

Tags: managed-package, 2gp, partner, patch, ancestor

I want to create a new version of my package  every time we try to do so we have the same errors:

1. Account.XXXXX__c: The entity: Account does not have history tracking enabled
2. Contact.XXXXX__c: The entity: Contact does not have history tracking enabled
3. Contact.XXXXX__c: The entity: Contact does not have history tracking enabled
4. Contact.XXXXX__c: The entity: Contact does not have history tracking enabled

Even if i add the settings in my project scratch.json file
"AccountSettings": {
"enableContactHistoryTracking": true,
"enableAccountHistoryTracking" : true

even if i enable track history on the field level metadata or on the object or on the settings Account settings.metadata nothing worked, and unfortunately we are stuck, thank you very much if you have a workaround because even if these fields are deleted it is still giving me the same errors.

It seems that when it reach the "verifying metadata" status  something block the process  and i am not able to create a patch for my current stable version installed on my org.